# How would i close opened qtip2 instance with timeout?

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I would like to close out qtip after 2 seconds, after user clicks trigger element.

Everything works fine up until that `settimeout` call.

When `setTimeout` counted down 2000ms i get is this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'toggle'`

I suppose it's something to do with that `api` does not contain what it should contain.

Code that i have:

```
jQuery('#action-bar-currency-control #currency_converter a').each(function()
        {
            jQuery(this).qtip(
                {
                    id: 'currency_changed_tip',
                    content: {
                        text: jQuery(this).data('currencycode')
                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'top center',
                        at: 'bottom center'
                    },
                    show: {
                        event: 'click',
                        solo: true
                    },
                    hide: false,
                    events: {
                        render: function(event, api) {
                            setTimeout(api.hide, 2000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        });
```

Anyone got any pointers here?

**EDIT:**
Did not figure it out, so i went with delay.

```
hide: {
    delay: 2000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do something like `api.elements.target.hide`

```
events: {
    render: function(event, api) {
        setTimeout(api.elements.target.hide, 2000);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Extract from api documentation http://qtip2.com/api

> elements
>
> An object containing references to elements relating to the tooltip, including the initial target.
>
> api.elements.target; // Reference to the 'target' element i.e. matched by $('.selector').qtip()
>
> api.elements.tooltip; // Container element for those below
>
> api.elements.titlebar; // Titlebar holds the title (and close button, if enabled) element(s) below
>
> api.elements.title; // Contains the content.title
>
> api.elements.button; // Close button defined by content.button
>
> api.elements.content; // Contains the content.text

So it looks like you want `elements.tooltip` not `elements.target`

Comment: Thing is i can see that api prototype has hide method and it returns this ``function (a){return this.toggle(D,a)} ``, but i believe ``this`` is not referring to the qtip but to each loops element and that's why it can't toggle it. Btw tried api.elements.tooltip and all others.